# Hooking network functions using a driver, a high-level overview?

Tags: c, windows, kernel, driver

I have just managed to write my first windows driver (havent registered it yet- but i managed to get the things created!).

I wondered if someone can give me a high overview of how I could achieve the following:

I would like to write a driver which will implement some behaviour when a network packet is received by the computer, before windows does what it does with the packet, i'd like to take this data and output it to the console of a C or C++ program.

Lets assume I have a C/C++ program written, which has a console. How does the C/C++ program *interact* with the driver I wrote which is hooking the network activity? Is it simply some C code which calls my drivers, the function returns the data as an object and then I can use that object to display in the console?

Thank you in advance for any possible replies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a driver for this task. Use packet sniffer library like [PCap](http://www.tcpdump.org/pcap.html) (actually you'll need [WinPCap](http://www.winpcap.org/)). It's really simple to capture packets and print them to console.

Alternative way is raw socket. But desktop Windows (as opposite to Windows Server) limits raw socket functionality.

Comment: I wanted to get to the packet before 'windows' does, im interested in high frequency trading and so i wanted to try and program really low level. Now that i have said this, does it make sense still writing a driver?

Comment: PCap is really low level because it provides a driver you're trying to implement, along with interface to user-mode applications. Why to do this again?

Comment: I didnt realise, i thought winpcap was a wrapper with lots of excess functionality which would make things slower. So do you think (assuming they're working in C or C++) the guys developing HF trading platforms would use pcap on linux too, because it would be pointless to write a driver? Or is there some performance guy by using a driver?

Comment: Yes, it can be used on Linux too. Yes, there's a big difference in performance writing own driver or using pcap, but I mean development speed ;) Probably a fact that people snifs heavily-loaded gigabit networks using PCap will convince you PCap is good enough. And it has a priceless feature - filtering capability. It's a great deal to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a driver, or have a requirement to manipulate or filter packets before they hit the windows network stack you need to look into filter drivers.

This filter driver can then expose a device file on which your user space application can then read/write. The windows DDK contains examples.